# how to pass a struct pointer from from c# to win32 DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct, arrays

I want to pass byte array from C# to win32 DLL for some processes in c++!

my c++ code

```
    typedef struct
    {
        int length;
         unsigned char value[10000000];
    } wavfile;

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int insert_In_Table(wavfile *w)
   {

    hashing HS( w->value , (unsigned int)w->length);

        return HS.insertIn_hashTable();
    }
```

and my C#

```
[DllImport("HashCplusDll.dll" , CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int insert_In_Table(ref Wavfile sample);
public static int recordNumber_old = 0;

public struct Wavfile
{

    public int length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 10000000)]
    public byte[] value;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // open file dialog 
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"; 
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        string location = open.FileName;
        byte[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location);
        textBox1.Text = location;

        Wavfile pass = new Wavfile();
        pass.value = array;
        pass.length = array.Length;
        int numberOfRow = insert_In_Table(ref pass);
    }
```

but i have this error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred
>   in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Cannot marshal field 'value' of type
>   'Wavfile': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array fields
>   must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray).
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I try some solution like as `out` instead of `ref` but again can't runing app.

What i should do?

Comment: Your C# struct declaration is not a match.  Not the real problem, you can't  marshal structures this large.  Consider fixing the C++ function and give it *two* arguments, the length and the array.  And beware that it needs to copy the array.

Comment: As written by Hans, and note that even in C/C++ you wouldn't pass by value a struct of 10mb! :-)

Comment: can you help me more? and give me simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by change value field to pointer

c++

```
typedef struct
{
    int length;
    unsigned char* value;
} wavfile;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int insert_In_Table(wavfile *w)
{

    hashing HS( w->value , (unsigned int)w->length);

    return HS.insertIn_hashTable();
}
```

c#

```
[DllImport("C:\\...\\HashCplusDll.dll", CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int insert_In_Table(ref Wavfile sample);
        public static int recordNumber_old = 0;
        //StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Wavfile
        {

            public int length;
            public IntPtr value;
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // open file dialog 
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string location = open.FileName;
                byte[] array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location);
                textBox1.Text = location;

                Wavfile pass = new Wavfile();

                pass.length = array.Length;
                pass.value = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(array.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(array, 0, pass.value, array.Length);
                // Call unmanaged code
                int numberOfRow = insert_In_Table(ref pass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is complaining because of the meta attribute for MarshallAs. You will want to change that to ByValArray.

Instead of UnmanagedType.LPArray use UnmanagedType.ByValArray

Comment: I changed it to `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10000000)]` but now i have this error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Internal limitation: structure is too complex or too large.

Comment: That's because that is too large of an array to pass like that. Make the size smaller

Comment: I need pass `.wav` File ... so it must large :(